# Iterate Over Char Array Elements in C

Tags: c, binary

This code is supposed to take a user's input and convert it to binary. The input is grouped into an integer array to store character codes and/or adjacent digits, then each item in the integer array is converted to binary. When the user types "c357", "c" should be converted to 99, then converted to binary. Then, "357" should be converted to binary as well. In the `main()` function, strlen(convert) does not accurately represent the number of items in array `convert`, thus only iterating over the first array item.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EIGHT_BITS 255
#define SIXTEEN_BITS 65535
#define THIRTY_TWO_BITS 4294967295UL

//  DETERMINE NUMBER OF BITS TO OUTPUT
int getBitLength(unsigned long d) {
    int l;

    if (d <= EIGHT_BITS) {
        l = 8;
    }
    else if (d > EIGHT_BITS && d <= SIXTEEN_BITS) {
        l = 16;
    }
    else if (d > SIXTEEN_BITS && d <= THIRTY_TWO_BITS) {
        l = 32;
    }

    return l;
}

//  CONVERT INPUT TO BINARY VALUE
char* convertToBinary(unsigned long int decimal) {
    int l = getBitLength(decimal);
    static char b[33];
    char bin[33];
    int i, j, k = 0, r;

    b[33] = '\0';
    bin[33] = '\0';

    printf("Bits................ %ld\n", l);

    //  creates array
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        r = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        b[i] = r;
    }

    //  reverses array for binary value
    for (j = l - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        bin[k] = b[j];
        strncpy(&bin[k], &b[j], l);
        snprintf(&bin[k], l, "%d", b[j]);
        k++;
    }

    printf("Binary Value: %s\n", bin);

    return bin;
}

unsigned long int* numbersToConvert(char* input) {
    const int MAX_INPUT = 20;
    int i, k = 0, z = 0;
    char numbers[MAX_INPUT];
    unsigned long int *toConvert = malloc(MAX_INPUT * sizeof(int));

    numbers[MAX_INPUT] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {

        if (isdigit(input[i])) {
            numbers[z] = input[i];
            if (!isdigit(input[i + 1])) {
                toConvert[k] = strtol(numbers, NULL, 10);
                printf("----- %ld -----\n", toConvert[k]);
                z = 0;
            }
            else {
                z++;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("----- %c -----\n", input[i]);
            printf("Character Code: %d\n", input[i]);

            toConvert[k] = (unsigned long int) input[i];
        }
        k++;
    }

    return toConvert;
}

int main(void) {
    const int MAX_INPUT = 20;
    int i, p;
    char input[MAX_INPUT];
    unsigned long int* convert;
    printf("------- Input --------\n");
    scanf("%s", input);

    input[MAX_INPUT] = '\0';
    //  PRINT INPUT AND SIZE
    printf("\nInput: %s\n", input);

    convert = numbersToConvert(input);
    convert[MAX_INPUT] = '\0';
    printf("strlen: %ld\n", strlen(convert));

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(convert); i++) {
        printf("num array: %ld\n", convert[i]);
        convertToBinary(convert[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have attempted to null terminate each string to prevent undefined behavior. I am unsure if certain variables, if any, are meant to be static.

Comment: `bin[33]` is accessed beyond its size. Access should be 0 to 32. Even out of bound access done for `input[MAX_INPUT];`

Comment: In C arrays are **zero based**. The valid indexes for `char array[n]` are `0 < n`. Your question is unclear, should `"c357"` be converted to `99357` or `99` and `357` as separate values?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin They would be converted as separate values. Why is it important to explain to me that arrays start at 0? I'm sure I've made errors but an example from the code might make that information a bit more relevant.

Comment: It is important to explain arrays start at zero so you don't do: `const int MAX_INPUT = 20;` and then `char numbers[MAX_INPUT];` and invoke *Undefined Behavior* by then doing `numbers[MAX_INPUT] = '\0';` which attempts to set the value of the address *one past* the end of your *Variable Length Array* `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to read your code.

Here you have something working (converting the number to binary):

```
static char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    char *saved = str;
    int ch;

    while(end > str)
    {
        ch = *end;
        *end-- = *str;
        *str++ = ch;
    }
    return saved;
}

char *tostr(char *buff, unsigned long long val)
{
    if(buff)
    {
        char *cpos = buff;

        while(val)
        {
            *cpos++ = (val & 1) + '0';
            val >>= 1;
        }
        *cpos = 0;
        reverse(buff);
    }
    return buff;
}


int main()
{
    char buff[128];
    printf("%s\n", tostr(buff, 128));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6sRC4C